# Filtering javascript async fetch response

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to validate an array S3 file URLs whether the file exists using Javascript's [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) method, and checking if the response returns a **200**.

The issue is, whenever I use the ***validateUrl()*** method inside [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) via the line:

`urls.filter(async (url:string) => await validateUrl(url))`

The returned array is not filtered and still contains all URLs even ones that returned a 404 from the validate method.

```
processUrls(['video-SD','video-HD','video-FHD']);

const validateUrl = async (url: string) => {
      const { ok } = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'HEAD',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        mode: 'cors'
      });
      return ok;
    };

const processUrls = (urls: Array<string>) => {
 urls.filter(async (url:string) => await validateUrl(url))
}
```

I'm very confused as to why this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Array#filter` cannot handle async callbacks. They just return a promise, which is truthy, hence nothing filters.

Comment: If that's the case, is there any workaround I can do to run the validation on the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't asynchronously request information in a `filter` callback that you base the return value of the callback on; `filter` doesn't understand promises and won't wait before moving on to the next item in the list. In general, you can't pass `async` functions as callbacks to things that don't understand promises (like `filter`, `some`, `every`, etc.). (The main exception is `map`, because `map` doesn't have to understand the return value from the callback, it just gathers those values up into a new array.)

Ideally, you want to give yourself a server-side operation that validates a list of URLs rather than doing them one at a time.

But if you're doing them one at a time, you'll need to request the flags, then use them in the `filter`, something like:

```
// Does all the validation calls in parallel
const processUrls = async (urls: Array<string>) => {
    const flags = await Promise.all(urls.map(validateUrl));
    return urls.filter((_, index) => flags[index]);
};
```

(Note that I've made it an `async` function.)

If doing all of those calls simultaneously and handling them in parallel is a problem (hopefully not!), you can do them in series, but it'll take longer in terms of wall clock time:

```
// Does the validation calls in series
const processUrls = async (urls: Array<string>) => {
    const valid = [];
    for (const url of urls) {
        if (await validateUrl(url)) {
            valid.push(url);
        }
    }
    return valid;
};
```